# ssh start GUI application on remote desktop

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, putty, gstreamer

I am trying to start a gstreamer instance and display it on a remote centos7 desktop using ssh.

I have followed a few posts on SE sites but feel I am now confused as to what is happening and why it is not working.
[How to Run a GUI Application on Remote Server's X11 Display via SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252821/how-to-run-a-gui-application-on-remote-servers-x11-display-via-ssh) and [putty x-11](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/putty-remote-x11-desktop-applications/)

Using root user for testing only on closed network (yes I know it is bad, but testing only)

```
Setup
Remote Machine
Centos7 - guest on virtualbox win10 host

Local machine
xshell-> connection -> tunneling -> foward x11 contections to X DISPLAY localhost:0.0
```

Step one,

```
confirm gstreamer is working on centos on guest
local terminal -> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink -->> player opens as expected
```

Step two

```
connect via ssh
export DISPLAY=0.0
echo $DISPLAY -->> :0.0
ssh terminal -> gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink -->> terminal shows text preroll as expected, but no local window opens on remote desktop
```

I have confirmed the remote command is not opening by also trying `firefox myPage.html` that opens using a local terminal on the remote box but not using ssh into remote box.

Do I have the display number wrong? if so ho do I determine what display to use?